# symfony2 SonataAdminBundle intl-ext error

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, php-extension, sonata-admin

I have dealt with this problem all the day, but i couldn't solve it,although i have followed the instructions.
I got these error all the time.:(

```
"require ext-intl * -> the requested php extension int is missing from your computer"
```

i have enabled the ext-intl in my php.ini in wampserver...and also downloaded ICU and followed the instructions in this link:
http://icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/trunk/readme.html#HowToBuildWindows

but, none of these efforts have made a change in getting that killing(!) error.

what else should i try to solve this issue?

Comment: make sure that you are enabling extension in the correct file

Comment: tnx dear zizoujab...
i've searched the whole directory of wamp and found 2 php.ini files...which the extension has been enabled in one of them...so enabling it in the other file solved the problem:) :|

Comment: your comment is accepted:-":)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all be sure that your server is isung x86 build (intl not working with x64)
- activate intl extension in php.ini directly
- copy all icu*.dll form php directory to apache directory
- make sure your console using the same php folder you just configured

source : https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataIntlBundle/issues/32#issuecomment-10745894

In my windows system I have two `php.ini` files at the flowing paths :

1. C:\wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z
2. C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apachex.y.z\bin

I don't know which one is in your path . just make sure to  add the extension in both of them to eliminate any doubt.

Comment: Thank you zizoujab.
I have tried the first 3items...
but how to make sure that my console is using the same php folder?If you making sure by adding to path environment, It's already added to the path.:(

Comment: You can find the proper path in your web server phpinfo() page, Loaded Configuration File entry.